# How to deploy Kafka on Google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka

I deployed Kafka on Google cloud, I changed listeners to

> PLAINTEXT://[internal ip address]:9092

And when I try

> sudo ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper [external IP address]:2181

I can get the topic on the broker. However when I try to produce message to the Kafka broker

> sudo ./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list [external IP address]:9092
>   --topic test

following error shows up:

> ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value:
>   5 bytes with error:
>   (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s)
>   for test-0: 1506 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time

I wonder what properties did I set wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `advertised.listeners` to the external IP so that clients can correctly connect to it. Otherwise they'll try to connect to the internal IP (since `advertised.listeners` will default to `listeners` unless explicitly set)

Ref: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs